# Can reflection bind a class to a new name?

Tags: java, reflection, binding, scriptengine

I am trying to let users of my program rename classes and methods in the class. The new names can be read in and configured at run time and they will call these classes and methods in a scripting language using Java Script Engine. I need a way to bind their new names to the real names of the classes and methods. I have been looking at Reflection but I do not think this can provide me with the capability I need, or is this even possible?

Ex:

```
public class RealName {
    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then in maybe Paython say

```
obj = new NewName()
obj.hello()
```

Tell me if this is impossible please!

Comment: When you edited my question you changed a significant/important aspect. I intentionally gave the method a different name when I called it in Python....Please edit this back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question from what I've found no you cannot use reflection to bind a class to a new name. In fact I found no easy way to do dynamic renaming.

What I did to overcome this was to write code from a string to a file, save that file with extension `.java`, compile that file, then use it with reflection or better yet use it inside a script using the Java ScriptEngine API (that way you can avoid the ugly reflection code and actually have everything dynamic and on the fly).

Here's a starting point for creating the file,

[Dynamic in-memory compilation](http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/)

And here's something for scripting Java,

[Scripting for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/scripting-140262.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the method names, but you can bind an instance of an object to a given name and inject that into the context of the scripting language.

This would only work for that instance of the class, not for instantiating new instances.

If you really want this you may be able to generate sub classes with the new name and method names in the target scripting language and inject them into to the context to get the effect you are looking for.

Having said all that I can't really come up with a good reason to do any of this.

Comment: This is a requirement of mine to make our applications more abstract and general. Because I am writing a sort of wrapper/binding of our API to any/every JSR 223 compatible scripting language they do not want someone familiar with one language and its own naming conventions to be stuck with using our Java naming conventions. For example in Java a function is camel case and begins with a verb and ends in a noun, but in Python their naming convention could be all upper cased nouns....this is the reason for implementing my question.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are trying to do, still don't think it's good idea. I think your likely to just create more work, especially as it means you will need a different version of the documentation for EVERY scripting language